# How do I concatenate textboxes to use DateDiff in MS Access 2010

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, textbox, datediff

I have textboxes that I want to use to work out the length of time between two time periods.

`Start`    `08` : `00`
`End`       `16` : `00`

`Break` `30`

I've tried using DateDiff("n",`08`&":"&`00`,`16`&":"&`00`) - (`30`*60) but get the #Name error.

I also then need to convert to hours minutes which if the above function worked correctly i'd used (DateDiff("n",`08`&":"&`00`,`16`&":"&`00`) - (`30`*60)) / 60 & ":" MOD(DateDiff("n",`08`&":"&`00`,`16`&":"&`00`) - (`30`*60)) to get `7:30` to display in a final textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the number of hours between the two times, minus the break, we could use:

```
(StartHH+(StartMM/60)-(EndHH+(EndMM/60)-(BreakMM/60)

((16)+(00/60))-((08)+(00/60))-(30/60) = 7.5
```

....as long as a shift never crosses midnight.

Or, same result:

```
StratHH-EndHH+(StartMM-EndMM-BreakMM)/60
```

---

**Alternate Method using `TIMESERIAL`:**

`(TimeSerial(StartHH, StartMM, StartSS) - TimeSerial(EndHH, EndMM, EndSS) - TimeSerial(BreakHH, Break, BreakSS)) * 24`

`(TimeSerial(16, 0, 0) - TimeSerial(8, 0, 0) - TimeSerial(0, 30, 0)) * 24 = 7.5`

...or formatted:

`Format((TimeSerial(16, 0, 0) - TimeSerial(8, 0, 0) - TimeSerial(0, 30, 0)),"HH\hmm\m") = "07h30m"`

`Format((TimeSerial(16, 0, 0) - TimeSerial(8, 0, 0) - TimeSerial(0, 30, 0)),"HH:mm") = "07:30"`

---

## Using Data Validation instead of Multiple Textboxes

As an example of how data entry could be simplified considerably, and user error eliminated completely, here's a form using Data Validation supplemented by a `Total Hours` box for quick verification.  Another good way to ensure accuracy is if scheduled shifts are available, actual times worked could be compared to notify of large variances.

[image: img]

I won't get into detailed explanation since it wasn't part of the question (and the OP seems determined not to change) but this only took a few minutes to slap together.

**`StartTime` and `EndTime` text boxes**
 - Format: `hh:nn;;"H:mm"`
 - Input Mask: `90:00;0;_`
 - Validation Text: `Please double check your shift time!`

**`BreakMins` text box**
 - Format: `0`
 - Input Mask: `00`

### Form Module

```
Option Explicit

Dim breakHr As Single, totalhr As Single

Private Sub BreakMins_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    UpdateTotal
End Sub

Private Sub endTime_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    UpdateTotal
End Sub

Private Sub startTime_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    UpdateTotal
End Sub

Sub UpdateTotal()
    If Nz(startTime, 0) = 0 Or Nz(endTime, 0) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    breakHr = Val(Nz(BreakMins, 0)) / 60
    '[startTime]/[endTime] textboxes hold full datetime for easy calculation
    totalhr = (endTime - startTime) * 24 - breakHr
    total = totalhr
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot simpler. Do you know an easier way to display the result as 07:30 rather than 7.5?

Comment: Thanks @ashleedawg. Just seen it.

Comment: You're welcome.  Shifts won't cross midnight, right?

Comment: I must'a made a million shift time/date-related formulas over the years...  It's easy once you get used it.  ...is there a reason you'  have to store  the shift times in 5 separate cells like that? (as opposed to 3)  If this is for a number of people'd shift, you might find it easier in the long run to use "standard" form of HH::MM in one cell.  (Or better yet Date & Time; and display only the date if desired.)

Comment: Thanks @ashleedawg. It's a form that a lot of non-IT skilled users will be using and I believe this method to be easier for them to fill out than them knowing they need to format their times with a colon.

Comment: @WillacyMe -  There are many ways to ensure that a colon is entered without adding extra textboxes.  Actually, compared to a a textbox with a "forced" colon, this method is ***66% "less easy"***, thus 33% more prone to error, which means elevated frustration.  Plus, on *you*r end, special coding considerations will have to be made any time that data is handled; as you'll find yourself having to rewrite built-in functionality. **Trust me**, I've been down that path. This could *seem* like a good idea in theory, but in practice will be an unnecessary headache for everyone involved.

Comment: @WillacyMe As a quick example I added an example form to the answer, which took only a couple minutes to slap together, and no special coding or math considerations are needed since start/end times are stored as datetimes (as is the standard).  **Also**, it's ***impossible*** for the user to end incorrect times (which took *no* programming to put in place).